# Como fazer uma função de auto soma em javascript

Tags: javascript, python, django

Como eu posso fazer uma função em javascript que muda o campo total_produções toda vez que um campo muda o seu valor no formulário?
Eu possuo o seguinte código
**Template**

```py
<form class="form" role="form" method="POST" >
 <table class="table table-condensed table-responsive">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Produção Científica nos últimos 3 anos</th><th>Quantidade</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
          <td>{{ form.pc_artigos_qualis_a1_cinco_autores.label }}
          <td>{{ form.pc_artigos_qualis_a1_cinco_autores }}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>{{ form.pc_artigos_qualis_a1_mais_cinco_autores_primeiro_ultimo.label }}</td>
        <td>{{ form.pc_artigos_qualis_a1_mais_cinco_autores_primeiro_ultimo }}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>{{ form.total_producoes.label }}</td>
        <td>{{ form.total_producoes }}</td>
      </tr>
</tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

Eu ainda estou aprendendo a programar em python Django, então, estou aberto à criticas do código!

Comment: Fiquei sem entender e só com essas informações fica dificil ajudar? Atualiza o que?

Comment: então, no código eu possuo o "form.pc_artigos_qualis_a1_cinco_autores" e o "form.pc_artigos_qualis_a1_mais_cinco_autores_primeiro_ultimo", esses dois campos são do tipo inteiro, e o que eu quero fazer é atualizar o campo form.total_producoes quando um deles alterar o seu valor

Comment: Eles são inputs do tipo text???

Comment: sim sim, são do tipo text

Comment: Você fez algum javascript?

Comment: não, eu estava apenas pesquisando sobre e testando no meu código mas não estava conseguindo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelos comentários eu entendi que você deseja somar valores e trazer para um outro `input` resolvi explicar com um exemplo minimo:

```js
function change() {
  let v1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("v1").value) || 0;
  let v2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("v2").value) || 0;
  document.getElementById("res").value = v1 + v2;
}
window.onload = (function() { change() });
```

```html
<div> 
  <input type="text" value="10" name="v1" id="v1" onkeyup="change()" />
</div>
<div> 
  <input type="text" value="10" name="v2" id="v2" onkeyup="change()" />
</div>
<div> 
  <input type="text" name="res" id="res" value="" />
</div>
```

Comment: exatamente isso! me ajudou a entender como acontece o uso do javascript de forma bem simples, obrigado!